# String Comparasion Help For Solving Logic Grid Puzzles

Tags: prolog, comparison

I am beginner to Prolog language and to solve a logic puzzle I defined

```
age(five).
age(six).
age(ten).
```

I want to write prolog code like , defining

```
age(five)<age(six).
age(six) <age(ten). 
or 
five < six.
```

How can I  write code like five is smaller than six without using numbers?

Answer (score 0):

For a problem as little as this one you could define the following predicates:

```
%isBigger(A,B) means A is bigger than B
isBigger(six,five).
isBigger(ten,five).
isBigger(ten,six).
```

Hope it helps!